# make list jump over an image

Tags: css, wordpress

I have the following design
[image]

`the Story of Us`, `The Style`, `Journal`, `Locate Us`, `the Contact`, that is all will be manage from wordpress dashboard > menu, so it'll be dynamic. now, how to make that menu jump over an image (L.tru logo) and continue untill last menu item, so the image will keep at center of the nav menu?

Comment: why down vote? it's easy if the menu is static..that's why I am asking here.

Comment: I think a bit more clarity here would help. The image you've posted is how you want your header to finally look, correct? You're asking how to get the menu items to split around an image to give that look?

Comment: yes exactly, @afishintaiwan

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the precise code - let´s assume that the structure of the menu is as follows:

```
<ul class="menu">
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
</ul>
```

We know that the logo appears after the second menu item. So we can use the following:

```
ul.menu li:nth-child(2) { margin-right: Xpx }
```

Where Xpx needs to be the appropriate width of the logo, plus the margins you want to have between the menu items and the logo.

However, since this may change dynamically - you may need to change this every time you change the menu since the menu item lengths will change.

A better way to do this is to actually make two WordPress menu´s: one located to the left of the logo and to the right. Then you can be more sure of the positioning.

A third, more advanced way, that is theoretically feasible is to use SASS and CSS calculations to calculate the appropriate margin more dynamically.

Comment: ahh good idea using two menus... thanks @robert-jakobson, I will try it.